# How to keep three div images on the same line?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create three separate rounded images on the same line. I managed to get two in the correct position but I can't get the last one to move up into the correct line.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
}

.image-left {
  content: url(https://s16.postimg.org/qm1wc2syd/alexandru_stavrica_166342.png);
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10%;
}

.image-centre {
  content: url(https://s23.postimg.org/57nxodezv/jorg_angeli_128760.png);
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.image-right {
  content: url(https://s3.postimg.org/ejuuxd6n7/jay_wennington_2250_min.png);
  height: 250px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="image-left"></div>
  <div class="image-centre"></div>
  <div class="image-right"></div>
</div>
```

[image: This is what it ends up looking like]

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a better way to do this, but here's one that works: https://jsfiddle.net/5ybLh6vy/

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="image-left">
        <img src="https://s16.postimg.org/qm1wc2syd/alexandru_stavrica_166342.png">
    </div>
    <div class="image-centre">
        <img src="https://s23.postimg.org/57nxodezv/jorg_angeli_128760.png">
    </div>
    <div class="image-right">
        <img src="https://s3.postimg.org/ejuuxd6n7/jay_wennington_2250_min.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.wrap img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.image-left, .image-centre, .image-right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the image tag and wrapping them around a div like this?

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
}
.image-wrapper{
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.image-wrapper>img{
  height:250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
       <img src='https://s16.postimg.org/qm1wc2syd/alexandru_stavrica_166342.png'>
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
       <img src='https://s23.postimg.org/57nxodezv/jorg_angeli_128760.png'>
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrapper">
       <img src='https://s3.postimg.org/ejuuxd6n7/jay_wennington_2250_min.png'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want them all in a neat row you'll have to add `float:left;` to all of them and or to the `.wrap` class but you would have to add `display:inline;` to each image which I think is the best solution. Problem is if the the viewport isn't wide enough it will push to the next line.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.image-left {
  content:url(https://s16.postimg.org/qm1wc2syd/alexandru_stavrica_166342.png);
  height: auto;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  display:inline;
}

.image-centre {
  content: url(https://s23.postimg.org/57nxodezv/jorg_angeli_128760.png);
  max-width: 25%;
  height:auto;
  display:inline;
}

.image-right {
  content:url(https://s3.postimg.org/ejuuxd6n7/jay_wennington_2250_min.png);
  height: auto;
  max-width: 25%;
  display:inline;
  padding-right: 10%;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="image-left"></div>
    <div class="image-centre"></div>
    <div class="image-right"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Click full page

Comment: That's not what he asked for.

Comment: He asked how to place them all one line. There is no way of doing that in the frame viewport without resizing. I figured since he set the height in the styling already he wanted it at that height. But I fixed it to work no matter the viewport size, to switch it back to how I originally set it for preset image sizes. change the height back to 250px and remove max-width.

Answer (score 0):

Float all three of the divs right, make them width: 33.33% and box-sizing: border-box.

This will make three evenly spaced images floated inline.

Answer (score -1):

You could assign `float: left;` for all of your images, and then set correct margins.